# Map two objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have two objects:

`let obj1 = { key1: 'someValue', key2: 'someValue2'}`

`let obj2 = { someValue: 'otherValue', someValue2: 'otherValue2'}`

values of the obj1 is actually a key in the obj2.

I want a new object as `let obj3 = { key1: 'otherValue', key2: 'otherValue2'}`

I tried with **Object.keys** and **Object.values** but didn't succeed. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries`.

```js
let obj1 = { key1: 'someValue', key2: 'someValue2'};
let obj2 = { someValue: 'otherValue', someValue2: 'otherValue2'};

const result = {};
Object.entries(obj1).map(item => {
  result[item[0]] = obj2[item[1]];
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `array#reduce`. Iterate through each keys in first object and then for each key, look up in second object to get value and put it in the result object.

```js
const obj1 = { key1: 'someValue', key2: 'someValue2'},
      obj2 = { someValue: 'otherValue', someValue2: 'otherValue2'},
      result = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((r,k) => {
        r[k] = obj2[obj1[k]];
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved my mapping the keys of the targets to the config value via the target's value.

```js
const obj1 = { key1: 'someValue', key2: 'someValue2' }
const obj2 = { someValue: 'otherValue', someValue2: 'otherValue2' }

const replaceProperties = (target, config) =>
  Object.entries(target).reduce((result, entry) =>
    (([ key, value ]) =>
      ({ ...result, [key]: config[value]  }))
    (entry), {});

console.log(replaceProperties(obj1, obj2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Code golf

As you can see above, the entire function can be expressed in one line. :)

```js
f=(t,c)=>Object.entries(t).reduce((r,e)=>(([k,v])=>({...r,[k]:c[v]}))(e),{})
a={key1:'someValue',key2:'someValue2'}
b={someValue:'otherValue',someValue2:'otherValue2'}
console.log(f(a, b))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```